# Assigning a derived object to a base class object without object slicing

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-inheritance

How can I assign a derived object to a static type of base and without heap allocation?

Basically, I want to know if this is possible:

```
Base* b = new Derived;
```

But without new and raw pointers.

Comment: `Base&& b = Derived{};` will work, although it does make me wonder why you need this in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't assign `Derived` object to `Base` variable by value without slicing - `Base` variable is just not 'big enough' to hold an object of `Derived` type. Think of it as you still need those `sizeof(Derived)` bytes of memory to hold an actual object.

However, you can avoid heap allocations.

Allocate it as an automatic variable:

```
Derived d;
Base* b = &d;
```

Or as a static variable:

```
static Derived d;
Base* b = &d;
```

Or as a global:

```
//Somewhere in global scope
Derived d;
//...somewhere in function
Base* b = &d;
```

Or even with [placement new](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax) on preallocated memory (*disclaimer: do not use this actual code*):

```
static char memory[sizeof(Derived)];
Base* b = new(memory)Derived;
```

Finally, raw pointers can be avoided with references, but then you lose the ability to change it after initialization:

```
Derived d;
Base& b = d;
```

Either way, you have to allocate enough room for `Derived` object, and you must ensure that it survives long enough, so you do not access your `Base` object after original `Derived` is destroyed.

Comment: Don't forget the issue of alignment.